# C++ [Error] assignment of read-only location '*(a + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)min) * 4ull)))'

Tags: c++

I have tried to write some print code, but there are always two errors. My teacher was really terrible, he didn't teach us about how to change const type context or address. I really need help, thank you so much.

There is my code, put an array, and sort it, but when I tried to exchange the a[min] and a[i], it noticed me wrong. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here instead of just linking it using an image

Comment: You can't modify the element of `a` since it's `const int[]`. Could you change the parameter type to `int[]`?

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Error] assignment of read-only location
```

The error means that you are trying to write to a location that is read-only, or in your case, trying to change a constant.

Change it from

```
void print_array(const int a[], const int asize)
```

to

```
void print_array(int a[], const int asize)
```

Comment: alternatively, think about why you are modifying the array in a function called `print_array`